# How to auto populate lookup required field in custom object

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I have custom object `service_hub__c`. In which  I have two required lookup fields with `account` and  `contact`. Now the problem is when I `go` to `related Section`  in the account object and click `new service_hub` button so its auto-populates the account name but how can I auto-populate the contact name(suppose the populate account have 10 contacts I only want to populate the contact whose `first contact``(first contact is checkbox field) is true. So how it possible? what is the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think that, in this case, the best way to do this would be using a Process Builder/Flow or even a trigger to achieve it. By using standard Salesforce capabilities, I don't think it is possible to default the value of the lookup the way you need.

As I said, a Flow or a Trigger would make the cut.

Comment: With Process Builder/Flow the value only populates when the record is saved. I want when i clicked on the new button the field fulfill

Comment: Then, I don't think there is a way to achieve this unless you replace the "New" button with a custom component solution.